# asp.net storing images

Tags: asp.net

It's me your junior programmer extraodinaire

I'm trying to display an image from my database but when I try to extract the file it only contains 6 bytes of data which causes my program to throw an error. My instructor informed me that the file is too small for an image, leading me to believe that I'm not storing it properly. I would be most gracious if someone could identify any code that might cause this to happen.

this is my function grabbing/storing the file

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim _image As Byte()
    _image = FileUpload1.FileBytes
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO mrg_Image(Image, UserId) VALUES('@image', @id)"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", FileUpload1.FileBytes)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 4)


    conn.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    conn.Close()

    'FileUpload1.SaveAs()

End Sub



    conn.Open()
```

file_bytes is the variable that contains 6 bytes as oppose to a thousand+ which an image should have

```
    Dim file_bytes As Byte() = cmd.ExecuteScalar()        
    Dim file_bytes_memory_stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(file_bytes)
    Dim file_bytes_stream As System.IO.Stream = DirectCast(file_bytes_memory_stream, System.IO.Stream)

    Dim the_image As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(file_bytes_stream)

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
    the_image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)        

    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `HasFile` true?  What is the size of the FileBytes array before you save it to the database?

Comment: What type of field is the 'Image' field?

Comment: What datatype is the field Image, and why the singlequotes around the image parameter's value?

Comment: @ Will: Thanks for responding - the length of the file is 1.2mb.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Image in my data adapter class is a byte()

Comment: @Bob: I'll look into the single quotes - think I was going by an example shown to me

Comment: @coding Gorilla: let me know if I confused your question

Comment: @Bob Bet those bytes are 40 69 6D 61 67 65

Comment: @user412318 - a *working* example using a *byte* field?

Comment: @Conrad Frix - thinking the same thing.

Comment: @Bob Sorry if your question is lost to me, how would I show you an example of using a byte field?

Comment: @user412318 - you said you were proceeding from an example. Did the example itself work? Did the example use a byte field? Did the example have the @image parameter in single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing '@image' with @image.

Also replace ExecuteReader with ExecuteNonQuery.

---

I wasn't aware of the FileBytes property, I've always done it so...

Dim _image(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length) As Byte
FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(_image, 0, _image.Length)

Comment: I receive some errors when I try to convert to a executeNonQuery says, "Value of type, "integer" cannot be converted to system.data.sqlclient.sqlDatareader

Comment: I just tried removing the single quotes and see what happens and I get a new error when I try to select the image from the db.error is: An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'http://localhost:1459/VS/images.ashx'. Wish I could put a break tag inside my ashx page.

Comment: dr = cmd.ExecuteReader should be just cmd.ExecuteNonQuery, no need to have a dr at all.

Comment: Also I think you also need... cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image)
cmd.Parameters["@image"] = FileUpload1.FileBytes from Conrad's answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO mrg_Image(Image, UserId) VALUES(@image, @id)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image)
cmd.Parameters("@image") = FileUpload1.FileBytes
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 4)
```

**Edit**
Removed ";" forgot this was vb

**Edit2**
Changed [] to (). again forgot my VB

Comment: got several blue lines - 1st saying that sqldbType.Image is not declared  and on the cmd.Paramaters["image"] = FileUpload1.FileBytes it says Property access must assign to the property or use it's values

Comment: @user412318: Don't know why you're getting sqldbType.Image is not declared. Its been there since 1.1. I fixed the second one which easy